# Deciding which Exception to handle

Tags: haskell, exception

In the context of deciding which Exception instance to handle for GHC versions >= 6.10, and given documentation for [getDirectoryContents](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/directory/latest/doc/html/System-Directory.html#v%3agetDirectoryContents), can it be assumed that getDirectoryContents will only throw IOExceptions? E.g. no exceptions will get past

```
let handler = (const $ return []) :: IOException -> IO [FilePath]
contents <- handle handler $ getDirectoryContents dir
```

... well, apart from stack overflows and so on, but no exception thrown specifically by getDirectoryContents? It seems to me, that this should be the case, but I don't see it explicated in the documentation, so I just want to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've never tried to read the code for System.Directory before, but looking at the code suggests that that's true. The only code related to error handling in the function definition is a call to `modifyIOError` which seems to add specific details like the function name and directory path to any IO error which is thrown. I had a quick look at the System.Posix.Directory module as well, and there are no obvious signs of errors other than IO errors being thrown there.

I just had a quick look though, so it's possible I missed something...

On the other hand, do you really care what kind of error it is at all? You appear to be trying to say "If something goes wrong, just return an empty list and carry on regardless". If that's all you want, why don't you just catch any error that gets thrown, instead of IO errors specifically?

What I mean to say is that the primary purpose of your error handler seems to be just to ignore errors, so why not just ignore them in general?

Comment: Yeah, the question is not so much about this specific piece of code, which does have rather simplistic exception handling, as it is about the added versatility of catching specific exceptions vs. the task of finding out exactly which exceptions are thrown where. Pre GHC 6.10, it seems there was only the opportunity to catch all exceptions, and we can get that same behaviour by specializing the handler to take SomeException, so there is nothing lost with the new approach - apart from the briefness of not having to explicitly declare the handler type, but to take full advantage of the (cont)

Comment: (cont'ed) new approach, it would be helpful if the documentation was more explicit about which exceptions could be thrown. At least it would be for me - maybe it is understood that IO monadic values can only throw IOExceptions.

Comment: I agree with you, the behaviour of functions when they encounter an error sometimes isn't specified in the documentation. And are no hard constraints forcing functions that live in the IO monad to only throw IOExceptions, although that's what they tend to do...